# change order of elements in a POSIXlt object and preserve class

Tags: r, datetime, posixct

Let's assume

```
x <- "2012-10-07"
```

where I convert it to POSIXlt using

```
y <- strptime(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I need to change to format to `%d/%m/%Y` using

```
z <- strftime(y, format = "%d/%m/%Y", tz = "GMT")
```

However this makes the object a character.

```
class(z)
[1] "character"
```

and when

```
as.POSIXlt(z, format = "%d/%m/%Y", tz = "GMT")
```

the printed result is

```
[1] "2012-10-07 GMT"
```

(but would expect it in the format of `%d/%m/%Y`).

Is there a way to convert `z` to `POSIXlt`/`POSIXct` object and preserve the (printing) order `%d/%m/%Y`? Should one even concern with this, since a "time" object knows where day, month and year are, and everything else is just for (pretty)printing?

Comment: If you don't like the print method you can write your own. I don't really understand this question.

Comment: @Roland I've amended the question a bit. So what you're saying is that the print of `as.POSIXlt` defaults to `%Y-%m-%d` and one should make a custom print method for anything other than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
x <- "2012-10-07"
y <- strptime(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

class(y) <- c("EUtime", class(y))

print.EUtime <- function (x, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S", ...) 
{
  max.print <- getOption("max.print", 9999L)
  if (max.print < length(x)) {
    print(format(x[seq_len(max.print)], format = format, usetz = TRUE), ...)
    cat(" [ reached getOption(\"max.print\") -- omitted", 
        length(x) - max.print, "entries ]\n")
  }
  else print(format(x, format = format, usetz = TRUE), ...)
  invisible(x)
}

y
#[1] "07/10/2012 00:00:00 CEST"
```

I'm sure you can modify this yourself to only output the date for midnight.